# how to add back android sdk to eclipse?

Tags: android, sdk

I have a problem here.

I just download eclipse 3.7 and previously using 3.6.

Now i want put android SDK into 3.7

i cannot download and install [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading) because already installed.

However i click menu -> window -> preference and did not see android path.

So how do i add in back the android plugin back to eclipse 3.7?

*p/s: black berry plugin need to be install too after android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Android Development Tools (ADT) into your Eclipse.

See here for instructions:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Once you've done that, if your Eclipse doesn't already point to the Android SDK, you can add it by finding the Android section of the Preferences screen and pointing it to the SDK directory

Comment: lol, see my question, i had installed the ADT before this, so do i need uninstall and reinstall again?

Comment: You mention an SDK but not ADT. They are different things. Do you have an "Android" section in your Preferences?

Comment: you need do these steps. Download eclipse 3.7, install ADT plugin, download android SDK and point to it in eclipse.
You have to install all into new eclipse! If you installed something into 3.6 it will be not in 3.7

Comment: never mind, i unstall all android and deleted all android folder.
Now i install 3.7 and download android sdk and adt

Answer (score 1):

Do the following...

menu--> window --> preference --> android --> (provide android sdk path where your android folder resides.)